# UIBarButtonItem tap area

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I create left Bar button item with next method:

```
- (void)leftButtonOnNavigationItem:(NSString *)imageName type:(NSInteger)type
{
    UIImage *backImg = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIButton *backBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, backImg.size.width, backImg.size.height)];
    if (type == 0)
        [backBtn addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(pop) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    else
        [backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(leftMake) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    backBtn.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    [backBtn setImage:backImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIView *backBtnView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:backBtn.bounds];
    backBtnView.bounds = CGRectOffset(backBtnView.bounds, -6, 0);
    [backBtnView addSubview:backBtn];
    UIBarButtonItem *backBarBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtnView];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarBtn;
}
```

I need add button on View because when I use CGRectOffset for button it is not work. So with this case my button on one od the UIViewController shown

[image]

So it is what I want. But UIBarButton began clicked only on UIBarButton (area of the rectangle). But when I add only button in UIBarButtonItem it is work even if I clicked on area of UINavigationBar that you can see on screen.

I add button like this:

```
- (void)leftButtonOnNavigationItem:(NSString *)imageName type:(NSInteger)type
{
    UIImage *backImg = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIButton *backBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, backImg.size.width, backImg.size.height)];
    if (type == 0)
        [backBtn addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(pop) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    else
        [backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(leftMake) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    backBtn.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    [backBtn setImage:backImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//    UIView *backBtnView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:backBtn.bounds];
//    backBtnView.bounds = CGRectOffset(backBtnView.bounds, -6, 0);
//    [backBtnView addSubview:backBtn];
    UIBarButtonItem *backBarBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn];//View];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarBtn;
}
```

and now my button shown like this

[image]

So CGRectOffset not work and my UIBarButton very close to left side of screen, but it is work fine by tap all area on navigation bar, that you see on screen. So I can touch in all area on navigation Bar and UIBarButton will work fine

So I need: UIBarButton must shown like in first case with more area from left side. But it must work by click not only button but all surround ares like in second case. What I must do?

**EDIT**
In first case button clicked if i tap next area

[image]

In second case button clicked if i tap next area

[image]

I need position of button like in first case (more origin.x from left side) but clickable area like in second case

Answer (score 3):

All controls/elements that can be interacted with inherit from UIView. UIView provides a method called `- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;`

It is possible to reimplement this method in your own subclass to increase or decrease the valid hit region of the view (or button in your case). For example, to grow the hit region by 5 points in all directions

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return CGRectContainsPoint( CGRectInset( self.bounds, -5, -5 ), point );
}
```

Note the negative values when using CGRectInset(). This is because the function is designed for *shrinking* a CGRect, so by specifying a negative value, the function will expand the CGRect.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `UIBarButtonItem` doesn't actually inherit from `UIView`, its an `NSObject` subclass.

Comment: @jszumski Whilst that is true, he was actually adding a UIButton as a custom subview of the UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: Does it actually work? Such `UIBarButtonItem` is deep inside implicit hierarchy of views so if it least one of its parents (including views controlled by Apple) doesn't have large enough frame, your `UIBarButtonItem` will never get the tap - that's how Hit Test works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use UIEdgeInsetsMake. It work for me.

```
UIImage *buttnImage=[UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
UIButton *backButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backButton setImage:buttnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
backButton.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, (buttnImage.size.width+leftMargin+rightMargin), (buttnImage.size.height+topMargin+bottomMargin));
[backButton setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(topMargin, leftMargin, bottomMargin, rightMargin)];

UIBarButtonItem *backBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems=@[backBtn];
```

Answer (score 0):

A view's frame is the size and position of the view within a superview (its parent). So when you go to set `backBtnView initWithFrame` try:

```
UIView *backBtnView = [[UIView alloc] 
                       initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(backBtn.frame, -6.0, 0.0)];
```

and forget about bounds all together, I think that will put you in the right direction.

Comment: not help =( same result - clickable area is only ractangle of button

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it in used accessibility frame.
Just set accessibility frame for button with increased height and width and it will work.